# Sent my ETH from Remitano to COSS but I cannot find my TXID on Etherscan. Why?

Tags: ethereum-classic, exchanges, wallet-transfer

I already made an ETC transfer from Remitano to COSS.IO. However, when I try to track my provided TXID, there is nothing in Etherscan.

TXID: 0x67c8b0b91db42d3184ef24cf6c6497295a02f113f0b3e4dad20b79529a86bbd4

Answer (score 0):

You should contact Remitano. Check your records to see which type of coin you transferred.

A search for this id as a Classic transaction on gastracker.io yields nothing at this time:

https://gastracker.io/search?q=0x67c8b0b91db42d3184ef24cf6c6497295a02f113f0b3e4dad20b79529a86bbd4

Etherscan explores the Ethereum Foundation network (**ETH**), *not* Ethereum Classic (**ETC**)

There is a transaction on ETH with this id (hash) but it is time-stamped Jan-13-2018 08:21:22 PM, more than 30 minutes after you posted your question.  Perhaps you transferred the wrong coins and, further, either Remitano or the Ethereum network may have experienced congestion.

As of time of writing this answer, the transaction is still pending.

The gas price of 0.00000002 Ether (20 Gwei) looks a little low, so it looks like it will be a long time before it is mined.

https://etherscan.io/tx/0x67c8b0b91db42d3184ef24cf6c6497295a02f113f0b3e4dad20b79529a86bbd4